# How to run bash script from NodeJS application correctly?

Tags: node.js, bash, memory, ffmpeg

I am running a node application that uses spawn child-process to start this script

```
#!/bin/bash
FILEPATH="$1"
COMPRESSIONPATH="$2"
ffmpeg -i $FILEPATH -vcodec h264 -acodec mp2 $COMPRESSIONPATH
sudo rm $FILEPATH
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -X GET 
http://localhost:3000/clovis/api/led
```

The script never finishes. If the ffmpeg compression command takes long then x amount of time then the process just stops and holds the process. I cant tell so by using the command ps-ef. Is there another way to start bash scripts from NodeJS other then spawn? Does the NodeJS child-process have a time limit?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed - Surprised no one solved this before I did. The child-process has options you can set to help the process separate itself from the node process.